# Google App Engine Prepaid Instance Hours

Tags: google-app-engine

From the application dashboard you used to be able to navigate to a menu option under Billing in order to access and set your prepaid instance hours. That menu seems to been moved or removed. Where is this menu now? How does one currently purchase prepaid instance hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't purchase prepaid instance hours any more.
since the new pricing announced this year prices dropped about 30% for appengine.
also there is a sustained use discount applied to the cloud plaform.
https://cloud.google.com/pricing/

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure since the Discounted Instance hours row is still visible in the usage reports. I thought maybe there was still a way to get discounted instance hours.